# Run menu on VS Code Mac greyed out

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im trying to to use the f5 and f11 shortcuts(stop/restart debugging, step over/into/out) on VS Code Mac, for some reason they are greyed out, cannot seem to find a solution.

Anyone have a solution to this issue?

thanks !